# How to count the number of items in a subset group of an array that are greater than a specific value within that array?

Tags: r, count, data.table, subset

I would like to count the number of items in a subset group of an array that are greater than a specific value within that array in R. See below example, for every year there is an external benchmark that is part of the given data (this is not the average of the dataset). For every row where the benchmark of a year is given I would like to add one column with the number of Males with a weight greater than the benchmark; and one column with the number of Females with a weigth greater than the benchmark.

```
> MyData
   year      type weight DesiredOutput1 DesiredOutput2
1  1990    Female     78             NA             NA
2  1990      Male     74             NA             NA
3  1990    Female     80             NA             NA
4  1990      Male     90             NA             NA
5  1990      Male     94             NA             NA
6  1990      Male     70             NA             NA
7  1990    Female     65             NA             NA
8  1990    Female     61             NA             NA
9  1990 benchmark     78              4              1
10 1990    Female     71             NA             NA
11 1990      Male     91             NA             NA
12 1990    Female     70             NA             NA
13 1990      Male     81             NA             NA
14 1991      Male     71             NA             NA
15 1991 benchmark     79              1              2
16 1991    Female     80             NA             NA
17 1991    Female     81             NA             NA
18 1991      Male     70             NA             NA
19 1991      Male     80             NA             NA
20 1991    Female     65             NA             NA
21 1992    Female     79             NA             NA
22 1992 benchmark     80              3              1
23 1992      Male     81             NA             NA
24 1992      Male     82             NA             NA
25 1992      Male     86             NA             NA
26 1992      Male     80             NA             NA
27 1992    Female     81             NA             NA
```

I can add a count for the number of Males/Females in a given year with below code:

```
setDT(MyData)[, Count:=.N, by='year,type']
```

But I don't know how to include the fact that I only want to count the number of Males/Females with a weight greater than the benchmark for the given year. Is there a way to use a reference to this benchmark value? I have seen several solutions when you want to count the number of values that is greater than a fixed number (e.g. greater than 70), but how can you compare with a value within your array?

Comment: Could you also post the output of `dput(MyData)`?

Comment: Why do you want all these NAs back? Don't you want just the counts per type and year?

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you need all these `NA`s. If you just need the counts, you can simply table by condition, here's an example

```
setDT(MyData)[, as.list(table(factor(type[weight > weight[type == 'benchmark']]))), 
                by = year]
#    year Female Male
# 1: 1990      1    4
# 2: 1991      2    1
# 3: 1992      1    3
```

Another option (probably a bit faster) is to select occurrences by condition and then `dcast`

```
dcast(setDT(MyData)[, type[weight > weight[type == 'benchmark']], by = year], 
                      year ~ V1, length)
#    year Female Male
# 1: 1990      1    4
# 2: 1991      2    1
# 3: 1992      1    3
```

Or similarly

```
setDT(MyData)[, type[weight > weight[type == 'benchmark']], by = year
               ][, table(year, factor(V1))]
# year   Female Male
# 1990        1    4
# 1991        2    1
# 1992        1    3
```

Either Way, if you insist to get the results back into your original data set, a quick way would be to join (but this won't produced the `NA`s), something like (using v 1.9.6+)

```
res <- dcast(setDT(MyData)[, type[weight > weight[type == 'benchmark']], by = year],
                             year ~ V1, length)
MyData[res, c("Female", "Male") := .(i.Female, i.Male), on = "year"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much David!!
I like your elegant solution with
setDT(MyData)[, type[weight > weight[type == 'benchmark']], by = year
               ][, table(year, factor(V1))]

But I was wondering if it would be possible to keep the column with the weight in this end result? @Colonel Beauvel
Thanks to let me know!

Comment: With your solution for the full dataset:

res <- dcast(setDT(MyData)[, type[weight > weight[type == 'benchmark']], by = year],
                             year ~ V1, length)
MyData[res, c("Female", "Male") := .(i.Female, i.Male), on = "year"]

I get the following error message:

Using 'V1' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override

Comment: Its not an error message. Rather just a warning that letting you know what's going on. Isn't the warning informative enough?

Comment: Hi David,

Thanks a lot! I tried the full version and that works!!
It was indeed just a warning :)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Here is another approach. In this version, you filter rows by weight for benchmark for each year. Then, you count how many data point exists for male and female using `count()`. You make the data format wide using `spread()`. You want to join this data with rows with benchmark, which is done by the first `right_join()`. Finally, you merge this data with the original data with `right_join()` again. At least this version avoids verbose filter and mutate parts in the previous version. NAs are generated by using `right_join()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

group_by(mydf, year) %>%
filter(weight > weight[which(type == "benchmark")]) %>%
count(year, type) %>%
spread(type, n) %>%
right_join(filter(mydf, type == "benchmark")) %>%
right_join(mydf)

#   year Female Male      type weight
#1  1990     NA   NA    Female     78
#2  1990     NA   NA      Male     74
#3  1990     NA   NA    Female     80
#4  1990     NA   NA      Male     90
#5  1990     NA   NA      Male     94
#6  1990     NA   NA      Male     70
#7  1990     NA   NA    Female     65
#8  1990     NA   NA    Female     61
#9  1990      1    4 benchmark     78
#10 1990     NA   NA    Female     71
#11 1990     NA   NA      Male     91
#12 1990     NA   NA    Female     70
#13 1990     NA   NA      Male     81
#14 1991     NA   NA      Male     71
#15 1991      2    1 benchmark     79
#16 1991     NA   NA    Female     80
#17 1991     NA   NA    Female     81
#18 1991     NA   NA      Male     70
#19 1991     NA   NA      Male     80
#20 1991     NA   NA    Female     65
#21 1992     NA   NA    Female     79
#22 1992      1    3 benchmark     80
#23 1992     NA   NA      Male     81
#24 1992     NA   NA      Male     82
#25 1992     NA   NA      Male     86
#26 1992     NA   NA      Male     80
#27 1992     NA   NA    Female     81
```

**FIRST ATTEMPT**

Here is my attempt to get the desired output. The following code is verbose, but it gives you what you want. First, you group the data by year. For each year, you choose rows having weight larger than one for benchmark. In the second filter, you exclude rows which weight is equal to that of benchmark; you keep rows with benchmark while you remove rows with tied weight for Male and Female. Then, you add two columns, one for male and the other for female with mutate. You count how many male and female exist for each year using table(). `table(type)[3]` is the count for male, for instance. Once you finish your job, you need to add removed data points. For that reason, you want to join the data and the original data with `right_join()`.

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(mydf, year) %>%
filter(weight >= weight[which(type == "benchmark")]) %>%
filter(!(type %in% c("Male", "Female") & weight == weight[which(type == "benchmark")])) %>%
mutate(male = ifelse(type == "benchmark", table(type)[3], NA),
       female = ifelse(type == "benchmark", table(type)[2], NA)) %>%
right_join(mydf) %>%
ungroup


#   year      type weight male female
#1  1990    Female     78   NA     NA
#2  1990      Male     74   NA     NA
#3  1990    Female     80   NA     NA
#4  1990      Male     90   NA     NA
#5  1990      Male     94   NA     NA
#6  1990      Male     70   NA     NA
#7  1990    Female     65   NA     NA
#8  1990    Female     61   NA     NA
#9  1990 benchmark     78    4      1
#10 1990    Female     71   NA     NA
#11 1990      Male     91   NA     NA
#12 1990    Female     70   NA     NA
#13 1990      Male     81   NA     NA
#14 1991      Male     71   NA     NA
#15 1991 benchmark     79    1      2
#16 1991    Female     80   NA     NA
#17 1991    Female     81   NA     NA
#18 1991      Male     70   NA     NA
#19 1991      Male     80   NA     NA
#20 1991    Female     65   NA     NA
#21 1992    Female     79   NA     NA
#22 1992 benchmark     80    3      1
#23 1992      Male     81   NA     NA
#24 1992      Male     82   NA     NA
#25 1992      Male     86   NA     NA
#26 1992      Male     80   NA     NA
#27 1992    Female     81   NA     NA
```

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(year = c(1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1991L, 1991L, 
1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 
1992L, 1992L, 1992L), type = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("benchmark", "Female", "Male"
), class = "factor"), weight = c(78L, 74L, 80L, 90L, 94L, 70L, 
65L, 61L, 78L, 71L, 91L, 70L, 81L, 71L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 70L, 80L, 
65L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 86L, 80L, 81L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27"), .Names = c("year", "type", "weight"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[ ,lapply(c('Male','Female'), function(x){
               sum(type==x & weight>weight[which(type=='benchmark')])
          }), year]

#   year V1 V2
#1: 1990  4  1
#2: 1991  1  2
#3: 1992  3  1
```